# Swf file cannot load another swf files (with relative paths) in WPF AxShockwaveFlash control (hosted in WindowsFormsHost control)

Tags: wpf, flash

I am using an AxShockwaveFlash control in WPF (hosted in WindowsFormsHost).

I have a player.swf file which uses external swf files from a folder (the path of the folder is relative to the player.swf file and the player.swf file works with this relative path).

I would like to play the player.swf file in the AxShockwaveFlash control but it cannot find the external swf files in the folder which is given by a relative path.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

axShockwaveFlash.Base sets the directory that the .swf will look for its resources.
Note that a path like @"C:\Resoruces" doesn't seem not work, a trailing backslash is required.
@"C:\Resource\"